# How to allow Google, Facebook bot crawler can index media files on AWS CloudFront?

Tags: web-crawler, amazon-cloudfront, googlebot, google-crawlers

I put media on AWS s3 & setup a CloudFront with short name for get image resource.

Ex:
1. my domain is : https://example.com 
2. cloudFront is : https://cdn.example.com 
--> example resource:
https://cdn.example.com/sample.jpg

And robots.txt files:
1. https://example.com/robots.txt

```
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cart
User-agent: adsbot-google
Crawl-delay: 1
```

2. https://cdn.example.com/robots.txt
   User-agent: * 
   Disallow:

But when I test index with Google Search Console it's alert me:
Crawl allowed?  --> **No: blocked by robots** 
Page fetch  --> **Failed: Blocked by robots.txt**

[image]

How to setting for CloudFront allow Facebook, Google bot crawler ?
Please help me resolve this problem.

Thank you !

Comment: According to the message, your `/robots.txt` file is responsible for the blocking action.  What did you put in that file?

Comment: Also, abcdef doesn't appear to be your real domain -- but it is *someone's* real domain.  If that is intended to be an example, please use http://example.com, which is formally set aside for this purpose.

Comment: I have updated more information about robots.txt --> please help me ! @Michael -sqlbot ! thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the update.  I don't see an obvious problem with the robots.txt file contents you are showing.  Can you provide the actual domain name?